# Replace values in a vector from values in another vector based on certain conditions

Tags: r, replace

I am wondering if I have a data frame with three vectors for example:

```
df <- data.frame (a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  b = c(10,15,19,29,13,22),c = c(9,9,9,16,16,19))
```

Now if I wish to replace the values in b to the matched values from the vector c if the value(s) in b is 2 standard deviation more or less than the mean value of b, how can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  b = c(10,15,19,29,13,22),
  c = c(9,9,9,16,16,19)
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    b = case_when(
      !between(b, mean(b) - 2 * sd(b), mean(b) + 2 * sd(b)) ~ c,
      TRUE ~ b
    )
  )
```

In this case though, there's nothing in the data your provided in column `b` that isn't in that window

Comment: Thank you Matt, the example is just a dummy one. Maybe I should make it more relative to my data. So I have many vectors, one is the reaction time row data, let's say vector a, and one is the mean reaction time per participant per condition, let's say vector b, and one is the reaction time standard deviation per participant per condition, let's say vector c. So what I want is to replace row data in vector to the mean data in vector b if the row data is 2 SD (vector c) more or less than the mean (vector b). I am wondering if it is possible in this case?

Comment: you should be able to use the same syntax as this

Comment: It pops up an error like this:
├─<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
│ Problem with `mutate()` input `RT`.
│ x `left` must be length 1
│ ℹ Input `RT` is `case_when(...)`.
└─<error/rlang_error>
  `left` must be length 1
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 9. dplyr::between(RT, RT.mean - 2 * RT.sd, RT.mean + 2 * RT.sd)

Comment: The syntax I used is:
Datav1 %>%
  mutate(
    RT = case_when(
      !between(RT, RT.mean - 2 * RT.sd, RT.mean + 2 * RT.sd) ~ RT.mean,
      TRUE ~ RT
    )
  )
where RT corresponds to vector a, RT.mean vector b and RT.SD vector c.

Comment: what is `left`? without your data, it'll be tough for me to debug

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have no idea what the left there is. If I run using the dummy data frame above with the syntax of df %>%
  mutate(
    a = case_when(
      !between(a, b - 2 * c, b + 2 * c) ~ b,
      TRUE ~ a
    )
  )
it still pops up with the same error message.

Comment: Can you post a `reprex`? The code above works fine for me in a `reprex`

Comment: I am not very sure how to use repress, but this is what I got: Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = TRUE) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Comment: you can do: `reprex::reprex({library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  b = c(10,15,19,29,13,22),
  c = c(9,9,9,16,16,19)
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    b = case_when(
      !between(b, mean(b) - 2 * sd(b), mean(b) + 2 * sd(b)) ~ c,
      TRUE ~ b
    )
  )})`

Comment: Actually, this syntax: df %>%   mutate(     b = case_when(       !between(b, mean(b) - 2 * sd(b), mean(b) + 2 * sd(b)) ~ c,       TRUE ~ b     ), works just fine. But when you replace a vector providing the mean and a vector providing the SD instead of using R to calculate, it does not work:

df %>%
  mutate(
    a = case_when(
      !between(a, b - 2 * c, b + 2 * c) ~ b,
      TRUE ~ a
    )
  )

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, and `c` all columns in your `df`?

Comment: Yes, like this: df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  b = c(10,15,19,29,13,22),
  c = c(9,9,9,16,16,19)
)

Comment: Right, but that's exactly what I have in my `reprex`. Can you try running my `reprex` and see if it works on your machine?

Comment: This is what I got:
``` r
df %>% mutate(a = case_when(!between(a, b - 2 * c, b + 2 * c) ~ 
    b, TRUE ~ a))
#> Error in df %>% mutate(a = case_when(!between(a, b - 2 * c, b + 2 * c) ~ : could not find function "%>%"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Did you do `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)`?

Comment: Yes I did. %>% has been working well in other syntax.

Comment: When I changed the code to this:``` r
mutate(a = case_when(!between(a, b - 2 * c, b + 2 * c) ~ b, TRUE ~ 
    a), data = df)
#> Error in mutate(a = case_when(!between(a, b - 2 * c, b + 2 * c) ~ b, TRUE ~ : could not find function "mutate"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The strangest thing is when I run this, it works fine
 df %>%
  mutate(
    b = case_when(
      !between(b, mean(b) - 2 * sd(b), mean(b) + 2 * sd(b)) ~ c,
      TRUE ~ b
    )
  )

Comment: Is that in a reprex? You need to have the `library()` call in your `reprex`

Comment: Ohhh sorry here it is:
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df %>%
  mutate(
    a = case_when(
      !between(a, b - 2 * c, b + 2 * c) ~ b,
      TRUE ~ a
    
    )
  )
#> Error in UseMethod("mutate"): no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Do you have your `df` defined in the `reprex` too? otherwise `df` is a function (density of the F distribution)

Comment: I copied and pasted the command you gave to me: reprex::reprex({library(dplyr)  df <- data.frame(   a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),   b = c(10,15,19,29,13,22),   c = c(9,9,9,16,16,19) )  df %>%   mutate(     b = case_when(       !between(b, mean(b) - 2 * sd(b), mean(b) + 2 * sd(b)) ~ c,       TRUE ~ b     )   )}). 
It pops up an error Error: unexpected symbol in "reprex::reprex({library(dplyr) df", which I don't know what that symbol is. ☹️

Comment: Yeah, you need to copy and paste the `reprex` from the answer and not the comment, becuase the formatting in the comments is bad